# Landing page without menu

Tags: usability, navigation, landing-page, onepager

I have come across a task that requires a landing page. The page has several sections such as " testimonial, partners, etc". When I asked if there would be any menu to make the navigation easier, the person in charge respond that he doesn't want the navigation in that page. Now my question is would that be ease for the user to navigate through the page and make a guess what a particular section is all about ? would it effect the user experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well designed landing page doesn't have a navigation, it doesn't need it at all. As an example, a small snippet from **[7 UX Principles for Building Higher-Converting Landing Pages](http://unbounce.com/landing-pages/7-ux-principles-building-higher-converting-landing-pages/)** :

> ## 1. Avoid distractions!
>
> A landing page has one job — to give people what they were promised in
>   the ad that got them there. You want your landing page visitors to
>   have just one task on your page: to convert. Make it easy for them to
>   do that.
>
> From a usability standpoint, distractions are a major killer of
>   conversions, **and chief among these distractions is the navigation bar**.
>
> Stef used an example from Marin Software to demonstrate the point.
>   What you may notice first about the image below is that this is not a
>   landing page. It’s a page that is supposed to convert leads, but it’s
>   just a page on their site. A page on a website isn’t a landing page
>   just because you send people there from an ad.
>
> [image]

And this is the whole idea behind a landing page: it's meant to be the container for a **[call to action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_to_action_(marketing))**. Not 10, not 5, not 2, but one and only one CTA. Anything that distracts the user from that purpose should be avoided. And obviously, a navigation bar is the main distraction, just like the article says.

Finally, for the same reasons stated above, be very careful with those sections. **Do NOT confuse a landing page with a home page**, they're very different things and they serve very different purposes. Home pages are broad in nature and they will act as an entrance for other sections or sub-pages. Thus, you'll have lots of elements.

Quite the contrary, *landing pages* have only 2 elements: **copy and CTA.** You can add some decoration, graphics, whatever, but once you weed out the *noise*, it's only copy and CTA

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question. In this case, anything that distracts the user should be avoided - Do you consider carousal behind the call of action a distraction ?

Comment: another element to avoid. See http://shouldiuseacarousel.com to understand what I mean